# How to merge a file with "Request" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in my project which should merge a file with 'Request',i just find that we can use the function of merge to merge the attributes,but how can we merge a file in laravel?thanks so much.

We can use 'merge' to merge some attributes

```php
$request->merge([
            'ticket_id' => '123',
        ]);
```

But if i want to merge a file?(i find this way is not workable, i can't not receive a file from the Request)

```php
$request->merge([
            'file' => fopen('xxx', 'r'),
        ]);
```

And the way likes this is not workable,too.

```php
$request->files = fopen('xxx', '');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put a file into the request? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a new UploadedFile and then add the file to the request bag.

```
$fileAddress = storage_path().'/file.jpg';
$file = new UploadedFile($fileAddress, 'file');
$request->files->set('file', $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example

```
$data = $request->except('exp');
$data['exp'] = $myVar;

// now use your data array
MyModel::create($data);
```